# Cannot call java method in javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am a newbie for jsp.  In jsp side, I have a button *capture*, my goal is when I click the button, my jsp code will call *callCapture()* in java side.  When I compile the program, the complier generates the following error message

> Cannot make static reference to the non-static method callCapture()
>   from the type Capture

at the **<%Capture.callPlay();%>** in jsp.  I think I have already set relevant variables to static, so I am not sure why it still gives me this error message.  A second question is that I am not what I am doing is the right way to call from java method in javascript.  Thank you in advance.

Java code:

```
public class Capture extends JFrame {
    public static JButton capture = new JButton("Capture");
    public static ActionListener captureListener;
    .......
}

public Capture() {  
    ......
    capture.setEnabled(true);
    captureListener = 
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                .....
            }
    };
}

public static void callCapture() {
    capture.addActionListener(captureListener);
}
```

jsp:

```
<body>
    <button onlick = "capature()">capture</button><>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function capture() {
        <%Capture.callCapture();%>

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can't do that at all.  You need to learn the difference between client-side code and server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

**<%=Capture.callCapture()%>**

and error message goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EL, try this:

```
${Capture.callCapture()}
```